Solving the Laplace equation on an infinite strip
I wish to solve $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ on the domain $(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times (0,a)$  subject to the boundary conditions
$$\begin{cases} u(x,0) = 0 \\ u(x,c)= \frac{x}{x^2+c^2} - \frac{x}{x^2 + 9c^2} \\ \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} u(x) = 0 \end{cases} $$
for an arbitrary fixed constant $c>0$. One approach is to employ the Fourier transform $\hat{u}(k,y)$ of $u(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ (where we employ the convention $\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ for the transform). The Laplace equation becomes $\hat{u}_{yy} = k^2 \hat{u}$, and so $$ \hat{u}(k,y) = A(k)e^{ky} + B(k)e^{-ky} $$
for some $k$-dependent constants $A$ and $B$. The initial conditions imply $A(k)+B(k)=\hat{u}(k,0)=0$ and $$ A(k)e^{kc} + B(k)e^{-kc} = \hat{u}(k,c) = -i\pi \operatorname{sgn}(k) \left( e^{-c|k|} +e^{-3c|k|} \right) $$ so solving for the constants, we have $A(k)=-B(k)$ where $$ B(k)=\frac{i\pi \operatorname{sgn}(k) \left( e^{-c|k|} +e^{-3c|k|} \right)  }{e^{kc}-e^{-kc}}. $$
Hence $$ \hat{u}(k,y) = \frac{i\pi \operatorname{sgn}(k) \left( e^{-c|k|} +e^{-3c|k|} \right)  }{e^{kc}-e^{-kc}} \left( e^{-ky} - e^{ky} \right). $$
But I'm not too sure on how I should invert this, and the consequent integration certainly seems messy. Another approach might be to use the general series solution to $\nabla^2 u = 0$ and fit the coefficients using standard orthogonality relations, but I doubt that the resulting series can be simplified nicely, as I'm told there's a 'nice expression' for $u$.
Questions:

Is the approach I outlined via the Fourier transform tractable?
Does the series solution approach yield an explicit (i.e. non-series) solution for $u$?


The denominator of the second term of $u(x,c)$ is $x^2+4c^2$ or $x^2+9c^2$? (I'm asking this because of the term $e^{-3c|k|}$ in your solution for $\hat{u}(k,y)$.)

@Gonçalo Thanks, fixed.

Does this answer your question? Solving Laplace's equation $\triangle u = 0$ in the semi-infinite strip $S = {(x,y): 0 < x < 1, 0 < y}$

Too long for a comment.
If $u(x,c)=\frac{x}{x^2+c^2}-\frac{x}{x^2+\color{red}{9}c^2}$, the problem has a very simple solution:
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+(y-2c)^2}-\frac{x}{x^2+(y+2c)^2}. \tag{1}
$$
It clearly satisfies the boundary conditions $u(x,0)=0$, $u(x,c)=\frac{x}{x^2+c^2}-\frac{x}{x^2+9c^2}$, and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}u(x,y)=0$. In addition, $(1)$ is a solution to Laplace's equation, as $u$ is the real part of an analytic function in the strip $(-\infty,\infty)\times(0,c)$:
$$
u(x,y)=\Re\left(\frac{1}{z-2ic}-\frac{1}{z+2ic}\right). \tag{2}
$$

Addendum
We can also arrive at the solution $(1)$ following your approach, but first we need to correct a sign error in $\hat{u}(k,c)$. The correct expression is
$$
\hat{u}(k,c) = -i\pi \operatorname{sgn}(k) \left( e^{-c|k|} \color{red}{-} e^{-3c|k|} \right). \tag{3}
$$
Propagating this correction to your expression for $\hat{u}(k,y)$, and noticing that
$$\frac{e^{-ky}-e^{ky}}{e^{kc}-e^{-kc}}
=\frac{e^{-|k|y}-e^{|k|y}}{e^{|k|c}-e^{-|k|c}}
$$
we have
\begin{align}
\hat{u}(k,y) &= \frac{i\pi \operatorname{sgn}(k) \left( e^{-|k|c} -e^{-3|k|c} \right)  }{e^{|k|c}-e^{-|k|c}} \left( e^{-|k|y} - e^{|k|y} \right) \\
&=i\pi \operatorname{sgn}(k)\,e^{-2|k|c}\left( e^{-|k|y} - e^{|k|y}\right).
\tag{4}
\end{align}
The inverse Fourier transform of $(4)$ yields $(1)$.
